# close auto complete of edge input

Tags: html, css

I want to write a login form.But the input label always auto complete when I click it.

```html
  <div class="container">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <form autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" required autoComplete="off">
                <label>Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" required>
                <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">Login</button>
            <p class="text">Don't have a account?<a href="#">Register</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I have set `autoComplete="off"`,but It dosen't work.Please help me.Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: I think there is a typo ❌`autoComplete` ✅ `autocomplete` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion so `autocomplete="off"` (but not sure 100%, try and tell me if that the problem)

Answer (score 0):

> Note: In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not
> prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to
> save username and password information, or from automatically filling
> in those values in a site's login form. See the autocomplete attribute
> and login fields.

Source: [MDN Docs AutoComplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

If you just want to get rid of the autocomplete while developing, I suggest opening it inside an incognito window, this will get rid of cache and the annoying autofill (Depending on your browser).

After a few Google Searches I found this, I have no idea if this will work haven't tested it, but you could give it a try:

1. Add `autocomplete="off"` onto `<form>` element;
2. Add hidden `<input>` with `autocomplete="false"` as a first children element of the form.

[Source GitHub](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, disabling autocomplete can be tricky in some browsers because despite what is coded on a page (such as `autocomplete="off"`), a browser may override this depending on a user's settings or browser extensions (such as password managers).

One ***trick*** is to use a value other than what would normally be accepted by the `autocomplete` attribute. So instead of `off`, you can use something like `testing` or `noautocomplete`. This likely isn't valid HTML, but does cause most browsers to disable autocomplete (*possibly because the value is invalid*).

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" required autocomplete="noautocomplete">
                <label>Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" required>
                <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">Login</button>
            <p class="text">Don't have a account?<a href="#">Register</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put `autocomplete="off"` instead of `autoComplete="off"`

Comment: @FUZIION You said "elements/tags are case-insensitive" but `autocomplete` is an attribute

Comment: I didn't, I don't have any more votes left today, I only commented